# Повторное использование id в функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с jQuery:

Радиокнопки 1 и 2 используют картинку с одинаковым id, но при этом должны открывать блоки с разным текстом.
http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/5/

В моем случае кнопка 1 не подгружает картинку, а вторая работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.radiobuttons').change(function() {
    if ($('#item1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic2, #text1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic2, #text1').hide();
    }
      if ($('#item2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic2, #text2').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic2, #text2').hide();
    }
     if ($('#item3').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic3, #text3').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic3, #text3').hide();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="img1" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img2" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img3" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/static/images/simple-image-resizer-128x128.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
<form class="radiobuttons">
  <p id="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1">Текст 1</p>
  <p id="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1">Текст 2</p>
  <p id="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1">Текст 3</p>
  
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text" id="text1" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
    <div class="text" id="text2" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
    <div class="text" id="text3" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="img1" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img2" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-41.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img3" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-44.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: У вас не должно быть элементов с одинаковым id на странице.

Comment: @Anamnian но как быть если мне нужно использовать один и тот же div несколько раз в сочетании с другими разными элементами? Это как раз такой случай

Comment: @AntonKuzmich, так и используй **один и тот же** див, а не другой с таким же id

Comment: @AntonKuzmich Для этого есть классы.

Comment: @Grundy у все дивов с картинками разные id

Comment: @Anamnian я, наверное, тупой, но вот вариант с классами и все равно не работает: http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/20/

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты используешь один id. Первое условие не срабатывает, т.к. во второй проверки у тебя этот же id скрывается. Вставь рабочую картинку в #pic1 и

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.radiobuttons').change(function() {
    if ($('#item1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic1, #text1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic1, #text1').hide();
    }
      if ($('#item2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic2, #text2').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic2, #text2').hide();
    }
     if ($('#item3').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic3, #text3').show();
    } else {
        $('#pic3, #text3').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если прям очень надо использовать только один и тот же ID, сделай так: http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/196/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.radiobuttons').change(function() {
   $('.img2, .img3, .text').hide();

   if ($('#item1').prop('checked')) {
        $('.img2, #text1').show();
    }
    if ($('#item2').prop('checked') ) {
        $('.img2, #text2').show();
    } 
     if ($('#item3').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pic3, #text3').show();
    }
});
});
```